# ASPX C# Search for a User in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Does anyone know the best way to search for a single user within Active Directory using `DirectoryServices`? I have code that currently lists all sub 'OU's' under a given LDAP path but I now want to add the feature of searching for a user under the path too. Could the code just be adapted to search for users?

I have included my code that lists all users in the current OU:

```
DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ouselect.SelectedValue + ";" + LDAPRoot, LDAPUser, LDAPPass);
DirectorySearcher ad_search = new DirectorySearcher(Ldap);

ad_search.Filter = "(objectClass=User)";
ad_search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ad_search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
```

Any pointer that anyone can offer would be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

    if(user != null)
    {
       // do something here....     
    }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

PS: the `PrincipalContext` has a number of different overloads for its constructor - you can also define a username/password to use to query Active Directory, and you can also define a "starting" container, if you need to. [Check out the MSDN documentation for details on this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there. Just change your filter to search for a particular AD Attribute, rather than all users.

`ad_search.Filter = string.Format("(department={0})", department);`

`ad_search.Filter = string.Format("(displayName={0})", "James Doe");`

`ad_search.Filter = string.Format("(sAMAccountName={0})", "some.username");`

Comment: You'd still want to include the base objectClass component of the filter.